# create a map in a pcd file using kitti datasets

Tags: ros, pcl, pcd, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to use kitti datasets- I have transformed kitti dataset to a rosbag file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269679/hi-guys,-i-m-trying-to-create-a-map-in-a-pcd-file-using-kitti-datasets,-can-anyone-help-me-?-i-have-transformed-kitti-dataset-to-a-rosbag-file/) by [ilyess](https://answers.ros.org/users/31717/ilyess/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-08-27

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-27**:
What have you tried so far?

**Comment by [ilyess](https://answers.ros.org/users/31717/ilyess/) on 2017-08-28**:
i had a subscriber to visualize kitti /kitti/velo/pointcloud topic, i have applied a statistical filter to filter the point cloud and i used voxel grid for down sampling, i want to save the hole point cloud map in a pcd file.

**Comment by [vkee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21470/vkee/) on 2017-08-30**:
I don't think that would necessarily create a map of the entire rosbag's raw data? See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try using NDT (normal distribution transform) mapping.

- [Open source implementation](https://github.com/CPFL/Autoware/blob/master/ros/src/computing/perception/localization/packages/ndt_localizer/nodes/ndt_mapping/ndt_mapping.cpp)
- [YouTube guide for creating pcd file using Autoware](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hsX4HX_XBM4)
- [Paper on NDT](http://aass.oru.se/Research/mro/publications/2013/Stoyanov_etal_2013-IROS-NDTOM_Fusion_Simultaneous_Mapping_and_Tracking_in_Large_Scale_Dynamic_Environments.pdf)

---

Originally posted by [ckirksey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29364/ckirksey/) with karma: 203 on 2017-08-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@ilyess, I would go with LOAM (it got 2nd on the KITTI odometry / SLAM evaluation).

If you use the velo_64 branch (https://github.com/vkee/loam_velodyne/tree/velo_64), it should work out of the box and you'll get a low drift map!

---

Originally posted by [vkee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21470/vkee/) with karma: 127 on 2017-08-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ilyess](https://answers.ros.org/users/31717/ilyess/) on 2017-12-30**:
Thank you very much , i went for it and it worked , but still i want to save the map in a pcd file, any ideas ?

**Comment by [vkee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21470/vkee/) on 2017-12-30**:
You should be able to use this function (http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__io.html#ga09bdff6c474655ebbefa8a97de669ece) to save the pcl Point Cloud as a PCD file.

**Comment by [ilyess](https://answers.ros.org/users/31717/ilyess/) on 2017-12-31**:
i believe these functions can only save only one capture at the time of map but not the hole map.

**Comment by [vkee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21470/vkee/) on 2017-12-31**:
You can use something like this function (http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_point_cloud.html#af2065290a879e08ec1f500a33e1cf086) to add all the clouds together into one cloud and then save that as a PCD.